# flutter: image overlap card

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'm new to flutter and i wanted to create simple design for menu app as shown in image below ... i tried below code but it didn't give same design, is there any way to achieve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSjOy.png)

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(test());

class test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _testState createState() => _testState();
}

class _testState extends State<test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Card over stack"),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 60,
              right: 10,
              left: 10,
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                    leading: SizedBox(
                        height: 150.0,
                        width: 150.0, // fixed width and height
                        child: Image.asset("assets/images/test.png"))),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack is the rignt choice, check screenshot below:

[image]

Full working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(const DemoApp());

class DemoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _DemoState();
  }
}

class _DemoState extends State<DemoApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 150,
              // replace with your Card here
              child: Card(
                child: Container(
                  width: 250,
                  height: 300,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 320,
              // replace with your image here
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 280,
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for this. You can also refer to the following link to learn more.
https://www.flutterbeads.com/flutter-position-widget-in-stack/

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          //add your gradiant here
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 180,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                  height: 500,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                  height: 200,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                  ),
                  //add your image here
                  //child: Center(child: Image.asset(name)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```